# Bias of sample correlation for discrete distributions

Tags: correlation, bias, discrete-data, pearson-r

Is there a proof showing the bias (or lack thereof) of the sample Pearson's correlation for discrete interval variables? In particular, I am interested in how such a proof handles the expected value of the sample correlation given the non-zero probability of samples with zero variance.